# Calculator with Functions

Tags: c, function, calculator

I wanna program a simple calculator. The calculations are in functions.
My problem is, the result is always 0. :(
What is wrong?
Look at my code please:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double addition(double a,double c);
double subtraktion(double a, double c);
double multiplikation(double a, double c);
double division(double a, double c);



int main()
{
  double z=0, a, c;
  char b;
  printf("Insert your Numbers to calculate!");
  scanf_s("%lf", &a);
  scanf_s("%c", &b);
  scanf_s("%lf", &c);
  if (b == '+')
  {
    addition(a, c);
  }
  if (b == '-')
  {
    subtraktion(a, c);
  }
  if (b == '*')
  {
    multiplikation(a, c);
  }
  if (b == '/')
  {
    division(a, c);
  }
  printf("Result:  %lf", z);
  system("pause");
}

double addition(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a + c;
  return(z);
}

double subtraktion(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a - c;
  return(z);
}

double multiplikation(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a*c;
  return(z);
}

double division(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a / c;
  return(z);
}
```

I program with Visual Studio 2013. I tried to debug the Program but this don´t work. Please forgive me my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code and it works properly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double addition(double a,double c);
double subtraktion(double a, double c);
double multiplikation(double a, double c);
double division(double a, double c);



int main()
{
  double z=0, a, c;
  char b;
  printf("Insert your Numbers to calculate!");
  scanf("%lf", &a);
  scanf("%c", &b);
  scanf("%lf", &c);
  if (b == '+')
  {
    z = addition(a, c);
  }
  if (b == '-')
  {
    z = subtraktion(a, c);
  }
  if (b == '*')
  {
    z = multiplikation(a, c);
  }
  if (b == '/')
  {
    z = division(a, c);
  }
  printf("Result:  %lf\n", z);
}

double addition(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a + c;
  return(z);
}

double subtraktion(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a - c;
  return(z);
}

double multiplikation(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a*c;
  return(z);
}

double division(double a, double c)
{
  double z;
  z = a / c;
  return(z);
}
```

Compile and then in input type: 3+2 [Press enter] and it shows the exact result!

P.S.
I deleted the 'custom' header and then used the simple scanf function.
I deleted the system("pause") too because I'm not under Visual Studio. (so you may need that)

So what I've done is:

 -  Deleted your custom header #include "stdafx.h"

 -  Edited the scanf_s to scanf(...)

 -  Added z = functions()

 -  printf(...\n) // not necessary

And it works.

Comment: With codeblocks it works! But why the fu** not with visual studio?!

Comment: What error does Visual studio give to you? paste it here

Comment: It gives me no error. look here: http://gyazo.com/60cc8e3d9189cad741cf15aab6f92e14 Just 0!

Comment: Try to replace scanf_s with scanf and insert the \n in the last printf. Tell me what you get

Comment: It's just a warning. Ignore that or use       #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS at the beginning of the file (before the #include) to remove the warnings. It won't have side-effects if you compile on GCC. Let me know

Comment: I disabled it and the it works!!! THX. Why it not work with that scanf_s? :DD best regards

Comment: Honestly I can't tell you why, but I do not recommend the use of Visual Studio at all. (even for the system("pause") ...). I generally don't recommend the use of Windows, but that's another story. Greetings

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere are you assigning the results of the operation to `z`. Instead of:

```
if (b == '+')
{
    addition(a, c);

 }
```

You should do

```
if (b == '+')
{
    z = addition(a, c);

 }
```

And likewise for all the other cases

Comment: Even with the change? While this may not be the only issue, it's definitely one thing that will cause the result to still be 0

Comment: Yes i added z= to all if cases. Can i scanf the operator with %c or %s?

Comment: My c is a bit rusty, I just noticed the lack of assignment. I'd try and narrow down where the problem is happening, (eg print something in the `if`s to see if you're reaching them, that sort of thing)

Comment: i tried it, the printf command isn´t functioning. :/ The mistake is then at the scanf...but where? :(

Comment: `printf` is not working? Try `printf("Result:  %lf\n", z)` -- note the `\n` at the end. Text output to the console may be buffered.

Comment: With codeblocks it works! But why the fu** not with visual studio?!